Minhag when Changing Money from a Tzedaka Pushka
I observed a minhag that when changing money with money in a tzedakah Pushka, not to change the full amount. For example, if you try to change 5 dollars into quarters one would leave the last quarter (or any amount) in the Pushka, hence only ending up with a lesser amount.
The reason I recall hearing is, that one doesn't use a Pushka for changing money, and by doing it this way it is considered giving a donation.
Does anyone know of sources for this minhag?

In the Sefer Laws of Tzedakah and Maaser Page 115 he quotes this minhag you mentioned.
The reason for this is found here:

The Gemara in Arachin 6a says: “[If one declares]: ‘This coin shall go
to tzedakah,’ before it reaches the gabbai’s hand (the one in charge
of tzedakah), it is permitted to change it. Once it reaches the
gabbai’s hand, it is forbidden to change it.” The gemara asks from the
story of Rabbi Yannai, who borrowed tzedakah money after it reached
the gabbai. It explains that he did so in order to tell others that
there were no liquid funds, and people would give more. Thus, his
borrowing helped the poor.   Rishonim differ as to the meaning of
“changing” money. Rashi and Tosafot (ad loc.) explain that the donor
could lend the money to himself or to others before he gave the
assigned money to the gabbai. The Rambam (Matnot Ani’im 8:4) seems to
relate the gemara to switching the coins to different ones of the same
cumulative value. The Beit Yosef (Yoreh Deah 259) finds difficulty
fitting the Rambam’s explanation into the gemara and incorporates only
Rashi’s into his halachic work (Shulchan Aruch YD 259:1).
There is much discussion among Acharonim on the question if the status
of a tzedakah box is like that of a gabbai or not. Without delving
deeply into this question, most treat it like a gabbai (see Tzitz
Eliezer XVI, 29 and Tzedakah U’Mishpat 8:(25)). It might seem then
that our question depends on the differing approaches to the gemara.
According to the Rambam, it is forbidden even to switch the coins in a
tzedakah box. According to Rashi, which the Shulchan Aruch accepts as
halacha, perhaps it is forbidden only to borrow the money, but it is
permitted to simply make change. After all, tzedakah money does not
have intrinsic holiness, making it religiously forbidden to use (Rama,
YD 259:1).
Rather, the pauper(s) has rights to the money. On the other hand, the
Rif (Bava Kamma 18b) seems to agree with the Rambam that after the
tzedakah has reached the gabbai, its coins cannot even be exchanged.
Furthermore, it is likely that the Shulchan Aruch argues with the
Rambam only regarding the gemara’s interpretation, not regarding
halacha (Aruch Hashulchan, YD 259:1). It is likely the same as using a
friend’s money without his permission. Indeed, is one permitted to use
money that someone entrusted in his hands? The Shulchan Aruch (Choshen
Mishpat 292:7) rules that it depends on whether the watchman is one
who deals in coins regularly and on whether the owner hinted as to his
feelings on the matter, but, as a rule, he may not borrow it. He does
not explicitly address the question of exchanging coins, which
Acharonim dispute (see Pitchei Choshen, Pikadon 5:(67)). Therefore, it
is unclear if one can use a tzedakah box to make change even when we
know of no specific reason that the recipients will thereby lose. This
justifies the stringent practice that when leaving even a small
donation, the act is considered giving tzedakah rather than taking
change, and it is permitted.
Besides the fact that not all agree to the stated reasons for
stringency, additional factors play a role. Regarding a general
tzedakah box which the shul’s gabbai administers at his discretion,
there may be an understanding that the money can be used for such
things as getting change (see similar cases in Netivot Hamishpat
301:9; Tzedakah U’Mishpat 8:8). This may depend on local practice. We
should also recall the gemara’s idea that when the poor gain from the
money’s use, it is permitted. The question is whether by using the
tzedakah box to get several coins in order to distribute (some of)
them to the poor one will give the poor more tzedakah. One must also
factor in whether he has left behind enough coins to enable the next
person to give a donation that requires change.

